# Advanced Apex Specialist - Please ensure that the Select One label was created

Tags: salesforce

I am working on "Advanced Apex Specialist" Superbadge but I am not able to pass challenge 1 as it keeps on showing me that Select one label is not created. But I have created it as you can see in below image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcOOb.png)

Tried creating another playground but still same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved by creating another Playground. Thanks!